# Show backorder status on magento frontend

Tags: magento, frontend

I need to show on the product page (frontend) that the current item is for backorder ONLY and is not in stock.

I have at the moment those in stock showing qty of what is available and those products on backorder doesn't show anything.

Does anyone know a code I can put in the view.phtml file that will ONLY show a message on those products set as backorder?

Thanks!

Simon.

Answer (score 7):

To do this make sure you have enabled backorders from inventory tab.

If you are on product page then first of all retrieve product qty.

```
<?php
$inventory = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);

if( (int)$inventory->getQty() == 0 && $inventory->getBackorders() )
{
  // No Backorders => getBackorders() = 0
  // Allow Qty Below 0 => getBackorders() = 1
  // Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer => getBackorders() = 2
  echo "display your backordedr message";
}
?>
```

You can also put this code in
`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\default.phtml` file where availability message of product come from.

Comment: Would this code go into the view.phtml? I added it in there and it just showed up as the code text... :S

Comment: yes you can add this in view.phtml? how you have put this code in your file? put this code in <?php ?> like syntax

Comment: How do I get it so it doesn't show up as code? When I add  this to my view.phtml it comes up on my site as the code text.

Comment: Hi Mufaddal, I am getting this message: Fatal error: Call to a member function getQty() on a non-object in /home/bigdecsl/public_html/app/design/frontend/fortis/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 103

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my answer (int) function is on wrong place

Comment: For anyone wondering where to enable backorders as Mufaddal suggests, that is in the Admin dashboard, under System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory.

Comment: Additionally, the `$inventory->getBackorders()==1` probably should read `>=1`, so that it also includes the setting `Allow Qty Below 0 And Notify Customer`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that you need to add in view.phtml. This will show the backorder message:

```
$inventory =  Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$inv_qty = (int)$inventory->getQty();
if($inventory->getBackorders() >= 0 && $inv_qty == 0)
{ 
    echo "Your backorder message goes here";
}
```